# How do I get "File -> Open in Realm Browser" menu option to work

Tags: xcode, xcode7, realm

Ever since upgrading to Xcode 7, I haven't been able to get the `File -> Open in Realm Browser` menu option to work. This was by far the most convenient option for me to view the Realm Browser. Has anyone else had any issues with this?

In the [repository documentation](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/plugin) , the instructions say:

> To install the Realm Plugin, open RealmPlugin.xcodeproj and Build. This will prompt for your password. After building the plugin, restart Xcode.

I've tried building/restarting several times and nothing happens. I don't get any logs or issues and it doesn't prompt me for my password either. I'm currently using Xcode 7.1 with Realm Browser 0.96.1. Any ideas? Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I'm one of the engineers working on the Realm Browser)*

Oh dear! I hadn't heard that that was an issue before. Thanks for that!

Sadly, Apple don't 'officially' support plugin integration with Xcode, so it's pretty common that when a major new version is released, plugins built for older versions stop working.

I've made an [issue on the Realm Browser GitHub page](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/issues/103) to look into this and see what we need to do to fix it.

Comment: TiM, thanks for adding it as a Realm Browser issue. I'm sure other Realm fans and supporters would appreciate it!